# "Failed to resolve Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission" error when I try to build my cross-platform Xamarin app for an iOS phone

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to deploy a Xamarin Forms project to an iPhone, but I keep on getting the build error

> Failed to resolve "Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission" reference from "Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" CyclePay.iOS

where the project's name is CyclePay. In response, I installed the latest version of Plugin.Permission (3.0.0.12) via Nuget, but I'm still having the same issue. Is the problem that the reference is coming from Plugin.Permissions version 2.2.1.0? If so, what should I do to resolve the issue?

Note that the project successfully deploys to Android, and also successfully deploys to an iOS simulator; it's just an actual phone I can't build for. I'm thinking it could also have something to do with the free provisioning profile and signing identity that I created specifically for this project, though I'm not sure what would actually be wrong in that realm. I'm programming in Visual Studio 2017, if that provides any useful information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Anoop Bhat

Comment: Try to delete the app from the device and try again, and also before deploying clean obj/bin files.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified this earlier, but the app crashes before it finishes building, meaning that the _build_ fails no matter what device I connect. It shouldn't be an issue with the device; it's an issue that occurs when I build _for_ a device.

Comment: Just for the next dev - I fixed this by removing and re-installing the permissions plugin. And deleting the obj and bin folder. And hoping. But not too hard. Xamarin can destroy hopes.

Answer (score 4):

I updated the library that was depending on Plugin.Permissions (in my case it was Xam.Plugin.Geolocator) and that resolved the error for me.